# WIX: reference a source file but not install it to the destination computer

Tags: windows, installation, wix, scheduled-tasks

I'm compiling an installer using Wix, and I'm trying to make it install a scheduled task. I've created an XML file with the details of my scheduled task (called BackupComplete.xml - using the export function in scheduled tasks). Now I want to reference it in a CustomAction so that at the end of the installation, the scheduled task is added.

Right now I have this bit:

```
<CustomAction Id="CreateScheduledTask" Return="check" Directory="Scripts" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]schtasks.exe /Create /XML BackupComplete.xml" />
```

But how do I reference my BackupComplete.xml file? I don't want BackupComplete.xml to be installed to the desination computer, it should only be included in the source .cab file so my CustomAction can read it.

I could add my scheduled task XML file like this:

```
<File Id="taskxml" Source="src\BackupComplete.xml" />
```

Inside a Component, but that'll install BackupComplete.xml on the target computer, which is what I want to avoid...

This is my entire WIX XML: http://pastebin.com/wFWd1zVc

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach is often used in the similar situations:

- add your temporary files to the `Binary` table. Use [`<Binary>`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_binary.htm) element for this
- in a **deferred** custom action:

  - extract the file
  - perform necessary actions
  - remove the file